# Running exec-maven-plugin multiple times in a single phase

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

I'm trying to test a client/server application, and using Maven to handle the build/test/deploy.  To test the application, I need to:

1. run an installer script (to install the server),
2. kick off a startup command (to start the service),
3. run the test (maven-surefire-plugin),
4. stop the service, and
5. uninstall the service.

Steps 1,2,4 and 5 will use the maven-exec-plugin.  Step 3 will use the maven-surefire-plugin.

The problem is that all 5 of these steps will occur in the 'test' phase.  Maven allows plugins in to be executed in a specific order.  the exec-plugin can be run multiple times by using multiple  entries.  The problem is that I need to use the surefire-plugin in the middle of the 4 exec-plugin executions.

Has anyone ever run into this before, or know how to structure the plugin's and execution's?

Comment: I think, you cannot optimize it. `maven-surefire-plugin` + `maven-surefire-plugin` + `maven-exec-plugin` is the only way you can do it (unless you're brave enough to write your own maven plugin that will combine that for you).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are trying to do sounds more like an integration test than a unit test. For this use case the [default maven lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) has three phases related to integration testing:

- `pre-integration-test`: perform actions required before integration tests are executed. This may involve things such as setting up the required environment.
- `integration-test`: process and deploy the package if necessary into an environment where integration tests can be run.
- `post-integration-test`: perform actions required after integration tests have been executed. This may including cleaning up the environment.

The surefire plugin usually executes in the `test` phase, but can be reconfigured to execute in another phase. Your steps 1 + 2 can then be configured to execute in `pre-integration-test`, while steps 4 + 5 have to execute in `post-integration-test`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <!-- Skip execution in test phase and execute in integration-test phase instead -->
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>surefire-it</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This is, more or less the route I went.  I'm not sure why Maven lacks pre-test and post-test phases, but using the integration-test phase will suffice.

Answer (score 10):

This is how I configured the exec and failsafe plugins.  I'm using failsafe, rather than reconfiguring surefire, since surefire is still running other tests to be in the test phase.  This will run steps 1 and 2 in the pre-integrationtest phase (multiple executions listed for the same phase will execute in the order given), run the test in the integration-test phase, and then clean up with steps 3 and 4 in the post-integrationtest phase.

(Note: I have echo commands in place of the real installation and cleanup commands)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <forkMode>always</forkMode>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>step1</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <executable>echo</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>foo</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>step2</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <executable>echo</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>bar</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>step3</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <executable>echo</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>baz</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>step4</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <executable>echo</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>woot</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>  
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: What version of the plugin is this with? I cannot get the plugin to execute with the <configuration> inside the execution in version 1.2.1