# Run additional files before creating war

Tags: gwt, maven-3

I have a GWT (2.5) maven project. I want to run some series of files before my **war** gets generated and it is no where related to GWT. I want to run some java files which compresses the images, organizes the imports and so on. Where should I start? I have limited knowledge of maven and gwt. Sorry for this idiot question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [***Exec Maven Plugin***](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) is the answer you are looking for. In the `<mainclass>` tag mention which java file you want to run. In the `<arguments>` tag mention all the arguments required by that program. You can run this ***exec plugin*** in any phase of your maven cycle and [***you can run it multiple times***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231626/running-exec-maven-plugin-multiple-times-in-a-single-phase). If you are running java file, make sure you mention **Java** in the `<goal>` tag.

**EDIT:** Of course you have to configure this in your `pom.xml` file

Comment: Thanks... exec maven plugin worked and double thanks for the link which enable me to run it multiple times as i had more than one file to execute

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit too broad, but ...

You need to research how maven plug-ins work. You add and configure them in your `pom.xml`. A guide can be found here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html

For your specific needs, I found the `exec` plugin on codehaus: http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/index.html

This will allow you to execute other java code when using maven to build your project.

Comment: Ya you are correct, sorry dint c this answer before otherwise I wouldnt have posted mine. I saw this after I posted my answer. It was about the same time.

Comment: We posted at almost the exact same moment. I might have beaten you except for the 1-2 seconds to get the first link :-D